# Trouble Installing Firebase Analytics to my React Native Android version

Tags: android, gradle

Ok so I believe I followed these instructions perfectly: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android

1) After completing the instructions I get this error: Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.4.

2) I go into gradle-wrapper.properties and change distributionUrl from

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

to

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

and re-synce

3) When I try to build after this I get the error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevMinSdkDevKernelDebugResources'.
```

In the Java compiler I get the error:

```
/Users/DJarrin/Work/dev_envs/****/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/src/main/java/com/learnium/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceModule.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I'm pretty lost and would really appreciate just some next steps to solve the issue.